# Disable the Dock in all but one Desktop/Space only

Tags: dock, desktop, settings, spaces, mission-control

On My iMac I usually have several desktops that I use for separate things.

While I prefer to have the Dock on my main space to access apps easier, I much prefer to have the Dock hide on all other spaces, except for the main one.

I know, that I can just do <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd> -<kbd>D</kbd> to hide/unhide the dock whenever, but is there a way, to have different Dock settings in different spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know, that I can just do <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd> -<kbd>D</kbd> to hide/unhide the dock whenever, but is there a way, to have different Dock settings in different spaces?

No, the *preferences* of the **Dock** are global between **Desktops/Spaces**, however, there is a programatic way to automate the toggling of the `autohide` *preference* of the **Dock** as you switch between **Desktops/Spaces**.

This requires an *application* to be *memory resident* and able to respond to the target *event*.

As an example, you could roll your own in **Xcode**, or use any *third-party application* capable of responding to a **Desktop/Space** changed *event*, determine which **Desktop/Space** you are on, and then toggle the `autohide` *preference* of the **Dock** to **hide/show** it based on the conditions, effectively pressing the **⌥⌘D** *keyboard shortcut* programmatically to avoid doing it manually.

---

With that said, I'll offer you a way that works for me and utilizes a free *third-party application* named [**Hammerspoon**](https://www.hammerspoon.org), along with using the free *third-party* **Hammerspoon** *module* [**hs._asm.undocumented.spaces**](https://github.com/asmagill/hs._asm.undocumented.spaces) to have access to the undocumented **Spaces API**.

Some **Lua** *code*, which is what **Hammerspoon** uses, along with some **AppleScript** *code*.

The *example* **Lua** *code* and *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown further below, was tested under **macOS Catalina** and **macOS Big Sur** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes all necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

In addition to **Hammerspoon**, the *third-party* **Hammerspoon** *module* **hs._asm.undocumented.spaces** to have access to the undocumented **Spaces API**, the **Lua** *code* and **AppleScript** *code*, as is and provided further below, all necessary **Security & Privacy** settings for operational control, one *preference* setting in particular is required to be unchecked in **System Preferences** > **Mission Control**:

- **[ ] Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use**

This is of course to keep the **main** working **Desktop/Space** as the first one in the *list*, thus having a *numeric ID* of 1, as ascertained by the *module* that provides access to the undocumented **Spaces API**.

This also assumes the **Apple** default *keyboard shortcut* to **hide/show** the **Dock** is in play.

> Option-Command-D: Show or hide the Dock.

<sup>From: [Mac keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)</sup>

Also, as coded, only a single display/monitor was used. Additional coding may/would be required for a multi display/monitor arrangement. However, not being able to test at this time, it is outside the scope of the solution offered herein.

---

- <sup>Note that the download and install instructions assume **Safari** and default *preference* **[√] Open “safe” files after downloading** checked.</sup>

### Download *Hammerspoon*

- https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/releases/latest
- Click the Hammerspoon-n.n.nn.zip link.

### Download ***hs._asm.undocumented.spaces***

- https://github.com/asmagill/hs._asm.undocumented.spaces
- Click the **Code** *button* and click **Download ZIP**

---

**Note:** During the initial install and setup of **Hammerspoon** and the **hs._asm.undocumented.spaces** *module* you will be presented with a number of **Security & Privacy** related *dialog boxes* and *notifications* to which you need to reply with an affirmative type response, e.g., **[Allow], [Open], [OK], [Allow Anyway]**. If the choice is **[Move to Trash]** or **[Cancel]** choose **[Cancel]**, or if the choice is **[Open], [Move to Trash], [Cancel]** choose **[Open]**!

---

### Install *Hammerspoon*

- Open the **Downloads** *folder* and drag and drop the **Hammerspoon** *application bundle* into **Applications**.
- Before you open **Hammerspoon**, add it to: **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**

  - **Hint:** Leave **System Preferences** open and unlocked as you will need it again shortly.

Open **Hammerspoon** from **Applications** or **Spotlight**, then:

From the **Hammerspoon** menu (hammer icon) on the **menu bar**, click it, then click **Preferences…**, and set them as follows:

**Hammerspoon Preferences**

**Behavior:**

- **[√] Launch Hammerspoon at login**
- **[√] Check for updates**
- **[ ] Show dock icon**
- **[√] Show menu icon**
- **[ ] Keep Console window on top**
- **[ ]Send crash data (requires restart)**

**Accessibility: Accessibility is enabled. Your all set!** 
         **Enable Accessibility** (Should be grayed out.)

Close **Hammerspoon Preferences**.

---

### Install the ***hs._asm.undocumented.spaces*** module.

Open: **Downloads**

Open the **hs._asm.undocumented.spaces-master** *folder* to verify the name of the included **spaces-vX.Y.tar.gz** *file* against the *commands* used in the next install step in **Terminal**.

Open **Terminal** and run the following *commands*:

- The current version of **spaces-vX.Y.tar.gz**, as of the day of this answer, is: **spaces-v0.2.1.1-universal.tar.gz**

  ```
  cd ~/.hammerspoon
  tar -xzf ~/Downloads/hs._asm.undocumented.spaces-master/spaces-v0.2.1.1-universal.tar.gz
  ```

Close: **Terminal** <sub>(Assumes no error from previous *command*.)</sub>

---

### Adding the Lua code to *Hammerspoon*

Open the **Hammerspoon** configuration *file* by clicking the **Open Config** *command* from the **Hammerspoon** menu (hammer icon) on the **menu bar**.

Add the *example* **Lua** *code*, from below, to the **init.lua** configuration *file* and save the *document*, then close it.

---

### Important Steps

In this next step the **init.lua** configuration *file* will get reloaded from the **Reload Config** *command* on the **Hammerspoon** menu (hammer icon) on the **menu bar**.

**Note:** The **Reload Config** *command* will fail because the **internal.so** *module* cannot be verified.

Click: **Cancel**

Then on the **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **General** *pane*:

- “internal.so” was blocked from use because it is not from an identified developer.

Click: **Allow Anyway**

Close the **Hammerspoon Console** *window* and the **Hammerspoon** *notification*.

Again, click the **Reload Config** *command* on the **Hammerspoon** menu (hammer icon) on the **menu bar**.

It should not error this time, but click **Open** to the message:

- macOS cannot verify the developer of “internal.so”. Are you sure you want to open it?

Phew! That's almost it! Your almost done and ready to go! Only one more security step to address when you switch spaces for the first time.

- “Hammerspoon” wants access to control “System Events”. Allowing control will provide access to documents and data in “System Events”, and to perform actions within that app.
  Hammerspoon needs to send events to automate applications.

Click: **OK**

---

**Yeah!** Now you are done and ready to change **Desktop/Space** and the **Dock** will then automatically hide on all **Desktops/Spaces** except the main one.

---

**Note:** The *example* **Lua** *code* for **Hammerspoon**'s **init.lua** configuration *file* is presented in two sections, the first is just the necessary **Lua** *code* and the second is commented *code* with **URLs** to each relevant **Hammerspoon API** and the **hs.asm.undocumented.spaces** *module*.

### *Example* **Lua** *code*:

```lua
spaces = require("hs._asm.undocumented.spaces")

function spaceHasChanged()
    local asCommand = "tell application \"System Events\" to return autohide of dock preferences"
    local ok, theDockIsHidden = hs.osascript.applescript(asCommand)
    if ok then
        local spaceNumericID = spaces.activeSpace()
        if spaceNumericID == 1 and theDockIsHidden then
            hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd", "alt"}, "d")
        elseif spaceNumericID > 1 and not theDockIsHidden then
            hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd", "alt"}, "d")
            local asFile = "/.hammerspoon/Scripts/FSAWWODS.applescript"
            local ok, status = hs.osascript.applescriptFromFile(os.getenv("HOME") .. asFile)
            if not ok then
                local msg = "An error occurred running the FSAWWODS.applescript script."
                hs.notify.new({title="Hammerspoon", informativeText=msg}):send()
            end
        elseif spaceNumericID == "" or spaceNumericID == nil then
            local msg = "An error occurred getting the active space ID! Review Console log."
            hs.notify.new({title="Hammerspoon", informativeText=msg}):send()
        end
    else
        local msg = "An error occurred getting the value of autohide for the Dock."
        hs.notify.new({title="Hammerspoon", informativeText=msg}):send()
    end
end

spaceWatcher = hs.spaces.watcher.new(spaceHasChanged)
spaceWatcher:start()
-- spaceWatcher:stop()



    -- The multi-line commented section below is the 
    -- commented code above, with URLs to each relevant 
    -- Hammerspoon API and asm.undocumented.spaces module.
    -- This is provided for users new to Hammerspoon 
    -- to help the user understand what the code is doing.

 --[[ 

    -- This module provides Hammerspoon with access to the undocumented Spaces API.
    -- https://github.com/asmagill/hs._asm.undocumented.spaces
     
spaces = require("hs._asm.undocumented.spaces")

    -- User created function for use with 'hs.spaces.watcher' submodule.
    -- Each time the Desktop/Space changes this function is called.
    -- https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.spaces.watcher.html

function spaceHasChanged()

        -- Use AppleScript to get the value of the 'autohide' preference of the Dock.
        -- https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.osascript.html#applescript

    local asCommand = "tell application \"System Events\" to return autohide of dock preferences"
    local ok, theDockIsHidden = hs.osascript.applescript(asCommand)
    
    if ok then
    
            -- The AppleScript command executed without error.
            
            -- Get the numeric ID of the currently active space.
            -- https://github.com/asmagill/hs._asm.undocumented.spaces
    
        local spaceNumericID = spaces.activeSpace()
        
            -- Toggle Hide/Show of the Dock as required. 
        
        if spaceNumericID == 1 and theDockIsHidden then 
        
                -- Press ⌥⌘D to unhide the Dock.
                -- https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.eventtap.html#keyStroke
                
            hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd", "alt"}, "d")
            
        elseif spaceNumericID > 1 and not theDockIsHidden then

                -- Press ⌥⌘D to hide the Dock.
                -- https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.eventtap.html#keyStroke
                
            hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd", "alt"}, "d")
            
                -- Use AppleScript to work around an apps window that does not 
                -- go to its own Desktop/Space when placed in full screen view.
                -- This is included and coded for VLC media player. Other apps
                -- that fall into this category will need to have their own
                -- code added to ~.hammerspoon/Scripts/FSAWWODS.applescript
                --https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.osascript.html#applescriptFromFile
                
            local asFile = "/.hammerspoon/Scripts/FSAWWODS.applescript"
            local ok, status = hs.osascript.applescriptFromFile(os.getenv("HOME") .. asFile)

            if not ok then

                    -- An error occurred running the FSAWWODS.applescript file.
                    -- https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.notify.html#new
                    -- https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.notify.html#send
                
                local msg = "An error occurred running the FSAWWODS.applescript script."
                hs.notify.new({title="Hammerspoon", informativeText=msg}):send()
                
            end
            
        elseif spaceNumericID == "" or spaceNumericID == nil then
        
                -- An error occurred getting the active space ID.
                -- https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.notify.html#new
                -- https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.notify.html#send
        
            local msg = "An error occurred getting the active space ID! Review Console log."
            hs.notify.new({title="Hammerspoon", informativeText=msg}):send()
            
        end
        
    else
    
            -- An error occurred getting the value of autohide for the Dock.
            -- https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.notify.html#new
            -- https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.notify.html#send
        
        local msg = "An error occurred getting the value of autohide for the Dock."
        hs.notify.new({title="Hammerspoon", informativeText=msg}):send()
        
    end
    
end

    -- Each time the Desktop/Space changes, run the user created function.
    -- https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.spaces.watcher.html
    
spaceWatcher = hs.spaces.watcher.new(spaceHasChanged)
    
    -- Start the 'spaceWatcher'. The commented 'spaceWatcher:stop()' line is there for
    -- convenience to uncomment/comment it and 'spaceWatcher:start()' and reload the
    -- config file from the Reload Config command from the Hammer icon on the menu bar.

spaceWatcher:start()
-- spaceWatcher:stop()

--]]
```

- <sup>**Note:** Because of the comments the **Lua** *code* is long. It ends with `--]]`, so make sure you highlight all of it when copy and paste it to the **init.lua** configuration *file*.</sup>
- <sup>**Note:** This *example* **Lua** *code* has been updated to include additional **Lua** *code* used in conjunction with the *example* **AppleScript** *code* in the **Update to Original Answer** *section* below.</sup>

---

### Update to Original Answer

This update is to address an issue found after posting the original answer.

*Applications* whose *window* when placed in *fullscreen view* and is not moved to its own **Desktop/Space** and hides the **Dock** will cause the **Lua** *code* as originally written to show the **Dock**, the opposite of what's wanted.

The *application* in question is **VLC media player**. There may also be other *applications* that do the same thing and additional *code* can be added to accommodate as/when needed.

Note that if you do not use **VLC media player** you should still do this so the *framework* is in place to accommodate any *application* that will require such a workaround.

I have updated the original **Lua** *code* I posted, and you will need to copy and paste it into the **init.lua** configuration *file*, replacing the original *code* in your **init.lua** configuration *file* with it and save it, but do not reload it until the next steps are taken. Use the information in the **Adding the Lua code to *Hammerspoon*** section above to add the updated **Lua** *code*.

### Adding the AppleScript *script* to *Hammerspoon*

In **Terminal**:

```
mkdir -p ~/.hammerspoon/Scripts
touch ~/.hammerspoon/Scripts/FSAWWODS.applescript
open ~/.hammerspoon/Scripts/FSAWWODS.applescript
```

Close: **Terminal** <sub>(Assumes no error from previous *command*.)</sub>

In **Script Editor**:

Add the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, to the opened **FSAWWODS.applescript** *document*, then save it, and close the *document*.

Close: **Script Editor**

With that done, you can now click the **Reload Config** *command* on the **Hammerspoon** menu (hammer icon) on the **menu bar**, as the update is completed.

---

### *Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
--  # 
--  # NOTE: Hammerspoon does not allow the use of the
--  #       AppleScript line continuation character.
--  #       Therefore code must be written in long form.
--  #       It also doesn't like the use of some characters
--  #       such as symbols for modifier keys and others
--  #       in comments and possibly in code as well.
--  # 
--  # Name: FSAWWODS.applescript
--  # 
--  #       Full Screen Application Window Without Own Desktop/Space
--  #
--  # Purpose:
--  #
--  # The purpose of this script is to workaround an issue in 
--  # hiding the Dock when an application is in fullscreen view
--  # and is not moved to its own separate Desktop/Space.
--  # 
--  # Currently this script is configured for the VLC media player.
--  # Each application that has this issue will need its own code.
--  # The code will be different based on the specific application.
--  # 
--  # The issue with VLC is that when in fullscreen view it hides
--  # the Dock thus causing the Lua code to unhide it. I suspect
--  # other apps that do the same thing will need to press the
--  # Option-Command-D keyboard shortcut again in order to counter
--  # the Lua code from unhiding it in similar scenarios.
--  # 
--  # VLC is only app I have encountered this issue with so far.
--  # 


tell application "System Events"
    set |fmAppName| to name of process 1 whose frontmost = true
end tell

if |fmAppName| is "VLC" then
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "VLC"
        tell menu item "Fullscreen" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Video" of menu bar 1
            set isEnabled to value of attribute "AXEnabled"
            set isFullscreen to value of attribute "AXMenuItemMarkChar"
        end tell
        if isEnabled and isFullscreen is not missing value then
            keystroke "d" using {option down, command down}
        end if
    end tell
else if |fmAppName| is "NameOfApp" then
    --  # Add additional 'else if' as needed.
    --  # Code for NameOfApp app goes here.
end if
```

---

**Notes:**

Just a reminder that this update is only applicable to *applications* whose *window* when placed in *fullscreen view* is not moved to its own **Desktop/Space** and also hides the **Dock**.

Because of this particular issue, the **Dock** will appear to bounce as the *value* of its `autohide` *preference* is toggled by the extra **⌥⌘D** needed in this instance. It is still better than having to manually press **⌥⌘D** all the time.

Comment: @Yassine Elshayeb, Just an FYI... After posting this, I found an issue with _apps_ whose _window_ when placed in _fullscreen view_ and is not moved to its own **Desktop/Space** and hides the **Dock** will cause the **Lua** _code_ as written to show the **Dock**. I have an **AppleScript** _script_ workaround for this issue to add to the existing _code_ and will be updating my answer to accommodate this, hopefully later today. The _app_ in question is **VLC media player**. There may also be other _apps_ that do the same thing and additional _code_ can be added to accommodate as/when needed.

Comment: @Yassine Elshayeb, I have undated my answer per information in my previous comment. Please take the time to apply the update, and sorry for any inconvenience it may cause. If you run into another _application_ that does then same thing as **VLC**, feel free to reach out for any coding help to add it to the **FSAWWODS.applescript** _sctipt_.

Comment: @Yassine Elshayeb, Please let me know when you've seen this update as I'd  like to rewrite the answer in a manner that includes the _update_ as though it was part of the original answer. This way it will be easier to follow for others that happen upon this looking for a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I have now seen your answer and don't mind you changing it to make it easier to follow! @user3439894

Answer (score 0):

I made an app specifically for this. In addition to the dock, it can also hide the menubar: https://github.com/a1usha/HideMyDock

You can download it from releases page.