# Can a Mac be programmed to simulate pressing a key at or immediately after the launch of an app or opening of a type file?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, pdf, preview, settings

I am trying to set the Preview app to not jump from page to page, but scroll between them and only show one column of pages, but I found that the relevant settings won't actually be stored, and will reset after a restart of the app or on the opening of the next file.

EDIT: although there is dedicated function for setting the default one or two page and scroll or non-scroll settings, however, for over 6 years, Preview is buggy, and won't be able to store it. After restarting the app, and opening a .pdf *for the very first time* it will still open it in 2-page, non-scroll setting.

To find the dedicated (non-operational) function:

Go to Preview > Preferences... > PDF > Opening for the first time: Show as > Continuous Scroll.

This is supposed to set the app to open with one-page continuous scroll even after the app is closed; however, it will NOT store this setting.

Comment: single page and continuous are mutually exclusive. Also see https://i.stack.imgur.com/undyO.png

Comment: anki — no they aren't; in fact, they are co-extensive. 
 https://imgur.com/a/xxtZWVU
https://imgur.com/a/uVNL8Ab

Comment: Statements like "some amazing '90's product manager at Apple figured out that you have", "Apple is intentionally trying to deter this sort of unwelcome user behavior" or "In an attempt to mislead, Apple" distract from the actual questions and are not considered useful. Also please don't take comments from others asking for clarification as negative, we encourage comments to shape questions into a way which will get them answered.

Comment: Having said that: I just looked at your video at https://youtu.be/A_RGZ8BStJo and see a clear distinction between Single Page and Continuous (line by line) scrolling. The question might be easier to answer if you edit a description of what you expect to see in terms of scrolling when you combine page-by-page and line-by-line scrolling directly into the question, including embedded screenshots. Please also state the version of macOS you are using.

Comment: As said, please make this less about Apple and more about what you want to accomplish. Also, edit the details into the question, comments don't help a lot here.

Comment: What is  Preview's Preferences->PDF Opening for the first time set to? Mine is Continuous Scroll and does exactly what you want

Comment: mmmmmm — I'm taking this back. And now you can take your negative back as well: This is what I tried few months back, and faced this issue: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4983102 MacOS used to fail to actually store this setting since no later than 2013. I bought this M1 Air the first week, and even though I complained to Apple with my AppleCare+ about this and a couple of managers looked at it. 3 months past, it still is present.

You can verify it for yourself by setting it properly then opening a .pdf you never opened yet. It will default to the disgusting non-scroll, 2 page shit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From *comments*:

> user3439894 — It seems like this would need scripting; I can't code much. Any chance you could share your method

Here are the two *functions* I use in my **init.lua** *file* for **Hammerspoon** to always set **Continuous Scroll** in **Preview**, especially in **Full Screen** *view*:

```lua
function applicationPreviewWatcher(appName, eventType, appObject)
    if (eventType == hs.application.watcher.activated) then
        if (appName == "Preview") then
            appObject:selectMenuItem({"View", "Continuous Scroll"})
        end
    end
end
appPreviewWatcher = hs.application.watcher.new(applicationPreviewWatcher)
appPreviewWatcher:start()
-- appPreviewWatcher:stop()

function spaceHasChangedForPreview()
    local asCommand = "tell application \"System Events\" to return name of process 1 whose frontmost is true"
    local ok, theFrontmostAppName = hs.osascript.applescript(asCommand)
    if ok then
        if (theFrontmostAppName == "Preview") then
            hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd"}, "1")
        end
    end
end 
spaceWatcherForPreview = hs.spaces.watcher.new(spaceHasChangedForPreview)
spaceWatcherForPreview:start()
-- spaceWatcherForPreview:stop()
```

**Notes:**

The *example* **Lua** *code* and *functions* used with **Hammerspoon** along with the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown above, was tested under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and works for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

The first *function* always clicks the **Continuous Scroll** *menu item* on the **View** *menu* whenever **Preview** is *activated* <sup>2</sup>.

- <sup>2</sup> The application has been given keyboard/mouse focus.

The second *function* always clicks the **Continuous Scroll** *menu item* on the **View** *menu* in **Preview** when the **Desktop/Space** changes, if **Preview** went into **Full Screen** *view* (or out of it) and **Preview** is the front most *application*.

In either case whether or not **Continuous Scroll** *menu item* on the **View** *menu* in **Preview** is already checked, this ensures it is.

The second *function* is necessary because if your screen is wide enough and **Continuous Scroll** is checked when the *window* is not in *full screen view* it automatically changes to **Two Pages** when going into *full screen view*. This keeps it set to **Continuous Scroll**.

Comment: @Almasy Sephirot, Let me know if you need any additional help with where to place the _code_ shown in my answer. Also, after saving the **init.lua** _file_ you need to click **Reload Config** from the **Hammerspoon** _menu_ on the **menu bar**.

Comment: @Almasy Sephirot, Have a look at my answer [A: Disable the Dock in all but one Desktop/Space only](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/419028/disable-the-dock-in-all-but-one-desktop-space-only/419597?r=SearchResults&s=1|30.1729#419597) as it has lots of good information on downloading, installing and configuring **Hammerspoon**.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed walk-through, I will get to making this work right now!

Comment: Omg, this is amazing! So elegant. I use similar macros (no scripting or coding though) on a jb iPhone, but that needs emulated touch events to be generated, it _seems_ by my cursory review that it does the same, but you cannot see it. It just simply makes it go full screen. It's awesome! This should get a lot of upvote, sorry, that I screwed my profile and can't give one. :(

Comment: Ooooh! Now I learned something here, I just did, this IS the answer for at least one half of the problem — and may not even be another half.

Comment: @Almasy Sephirot, RE: "and may not even be another half" -- What is the other half?

Comment: Did _you_ upvote the question?

Comment: I'm wondering if the issue is still present when not going full screen but just opening a not-before-opened .pdf in non-full screen. Would the built-in settings allow for the same? To me it does seem it actually does. What do you think?

Comment: @Almasy Sephirot, The default setting is for **Continuous Scroll**, however this can be ignored on a previously opened file if it was closed while set to something else. If you want to ensure a previously open file open in **Continuous Scroll**, then the *~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.ViewState.plist* file needs to be deleted. If you want that, then I'll see it it can be added to the **Lua** _code_.

Comment: Thank you for the up vote, if Preview could open one-page scroll view that would be amazing! I hope I’ll get to also upvote this answer later.

Comment: @Almasy Sephirot, RE: "if Preview could open one-page scroll view that would be amazing! " --  Please clarify what it is that you want. From your OP I was under the impression you want **Continuous Scroll**, is that not correct?

Comment: Apologies: Well, if you also found it useful, I tried to explain I sought non-double page **and** continuous scroll, just like what you set up in **Hammerspoon** with your .lua script to do when you go full screen

Comment: So I tested the non-full screen mode of Preview, and it _does_ work that way if you set it correctly, and it can store that setting. All is perfect. Maybe you could incorporate the detailed walk through in your answer for others to use it too! I, for one, am perfectly happy with this solution. It works like how it should out of the box. But, hey, maybe it's just me being noob, and needing this much a help — thanks for coming at my rescue once again! Super satisfied with the machine right now.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't get exactly what you want.

The nearest way is to go to Preferences in Preview.app and on the PDF tab there is an entry for Opening for the first time. This should be set to Continuous scroll.

[image: Preference Pane]

For most cases you will get one page and you can scroll by lines etc.

The reason that is not exactly what you want is that if you make the Preview window full screen and it is wide enough to show two pages it will show two pages

Comment: RE: "The reason that is not exactly what you want is that if you make the Preview window full screen and it is wide enough to show two pages it will show two pages" -- If one has [**Hammerspoon**](https://www.hammerspoon.org), one can make any **Preview** _window_  that goes into **Full Screen** _view_ automatically set to **Continuous Scroll**. I do it on my system, as that is my preferred viewing method when in full screen view in **Preview**.

Comment: mmmmmm — unfortunately, that setting is not stored after closing the app. Preview can store your preference for a certain file, and it typically restores the setting you had before, but other files will open in two page non-scroll, showing only the first page (in this case, if you turn to the second page, and there is sufficient width, it will actually show two pages, too!)

Comment: user3439894 — thank you SO MUCH! I am jumping to set this up. If this doesn't provide an over-all solution, and would only patch certain use cases, I'll be glad to share how I'm making it easier to jump in this view a little quicker and more efficiently.

Comment: user3439894 — It seems like this would need scripting; I can't code much. Any chance you could share your method or a step-by-step guide to replicate it? Thank you!

Comment: @AlmasySephirot It is saved - well at least on all the versions of OSX I have used - on Big Sur now

Comment: @AlmasySephirot, **Preview** saves the _view state_ of a _document_ in: **~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.ViewState.plist**

Comment: @user3439894 Precisely. It saves on a per document basis, but won't function as it suggests, that is, open it in a certain way on the first time your open a document.